# Ajaxを使用してJSONデータの取得をクラス式で実現するには？

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

非同期通信でJSONデータの取得をクラス式で実現するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
HTML上のボタン押下後に画像を表示できるようにしたいんですが、クラス式での方法を色々調べてもわかりませんでした。わかる方お力を貸していただきたいです。
まだエンジニアの学習を始めて数ヶ月でわからない事だらけなのでお手柔らかにお願いいたします。

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const dogImg = document.getElementById("dogImg");

// ボタンをクリックしたらイベント発動
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch("https://example.com/api") // APIのURL
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
      // imgタグに取得したURL画像を入れる
      dogImg.src = myJson["message"];
    });
});
```

Comment: 現状はボタンをクリックするとどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「クラス式で」は https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class のことで合ってますか? なぜクラス式にしたいのですか?

Comment: ＠merino 現状クリックしてもできてはいますがこれをクラス式での方法が調べてもわかりません。

Comment: ＠int32_t 合っています！質問したコードでのやり方はわかったんですががどうすればいいのかわかりません。現在クラス式を勉強中です。

Comment: このコードでクラス式を使う理由が思い当たらないので、回答できません。どんなクラスを定義したいのでしょうか? クラス宣言はなくクラス式にする理由はありますか? https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

Comment: @int32_t　申し訳ありません。クラス宣言です。

Comment: 依然として、どういうクラスを宣言したいのか不明です。単に技術的興味だったりしますか?

Comment: @int32_t　なんとなくしかわからないのもありますしわからないので例として知りたいです。お願いします。

Comment: リビジョン4をロールバックしました。質問内容が変わるような変更はやめるようお願いします。回答が意味不明になってしまいますので。別の疑問が出たのでしたら、この質問はクローズして、新たな質問を立ててください。

Answer (score 1):

たとえば「整数の乗算を足し算に置き換える」とか「三項演算子を`if`に置き換える」のような要求であればそれだけの情報でコードを書くことが可能ですが、クラスを定義するには「何を表現するクラスなのか」の情報が必要です。
質問文のコードとコメントからはそれが不明で、とくにクラスを利用するメリットも思い浮かばないので「クラスを使ったコードに書き換える必要はない」が回答になります。

---

以下のような状況ならクラスが絡んでくる可能性はあるかな、という候補はありました。

- `addEventListener()` の第2引数に、あるクラスのインスタンスを渡したい
- `addEventListener()` の第2引数に、あるクラスのメソッドを渡したい
- このクリックの挙動を組み込んだ[カスタム要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)を定義したい
- 外部APIへのアクセスをカプセル化したクラスを定義したい